# Converter string char* para std::string

Tags: c++, string

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
void splitstr(std::string &modulo, std::string &nmodulo, int &fk)
{
    string frase = modulo;
    string aux = "";
    stringstream strs;

    for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++)
    {
       switch(frase[i])
       {
            case 'c':
                aux = "";
                break;
            default:
                aux = aux + frase[i];
                break;
       }
    }

    nmodulo = aux;
    strs(nmodulo);

    strs >> fk;
}
```

Cujo erro é:

> error: no match for call to '(std::stringstream {aka
>   std::basic_stringstream}) (std::string&)'

Answer (score 2):

Conversão de std::string para const char * é só usar a função c_str() da str::string, ex:

```
std::string str= "String";
const char * ch_prt= str.c_str();
```

Conversão de std::string para char * é só usar a função c_str() da str::string e copiar para um char *, ex:

```
std::string str= "String";
char * ch_prt = (char*) calloc(str.length()+1, sizeof(char*));
strcpy(ch_prt, str.c_str());
```

Conversão de char* ou const char* para std::str é só usar cast direto, ex:

```
char * ch_prt = "LOL";
std::string str = (std::string) ch_prt;
```